# plone.outputfilters and collective.easytemplate

Tags: plone

I'm using plone.outputfilters (1.1) to replace the resolveuid links generated by CKEditor (or any Plone editor configured to generate resolveuid links). This works fine in normal pages. However it does not work with Templated Documents generated by easytemplate (0.7.9). Is plone.outputfilters limited to replacing links on normal pages only?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collective.easytemplate does not utilize the same HTML transforms as normal pages do

- Easy Template was created before plone.outputfilters
- Easy Template is designed to output raw HTML and there has been issues before with filters like safe HTML corrupting the raw HTML output

Supporting plone.outputfilters functionality to Easy Template would be a feature request which you can fill in here:

http://plone.org/products/easy-template/issues/

Please find a sponsor for your feature request and Plone community can guide you how to get the product patched.

Comment: Have put in a feature request:http://plone.org/products/easy-template/issues/13. I will update my links to static links for now. Thanks for your help.